# How to show production.log content in rails to user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to show production.log content in rails in html page ?

In case admin wants the log for payment functionalities, how can we show it in html pages ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do u need that? If it for debug - u can run sever in debug mode, if it for functionallity - u better create new table for output payments in it, or test for present after .save.

Comment: admin wants the logs to view in his admin pages for payment, api response, etc

Comment: It will be more much better way - make some functionallirt for output data for payment, api and etc. U can add some triggers like in model Payment after_save :add_log_for payment

Comment: Will  it be a thread safe?

Comment: Yes, sure, did u want example? Or u know how delayed_job works at ror ?

Comment: Ok, thank you, Let me try

Answer (score 0):

You can load any file from disk and show it in a page. Put this code somewhere in a controller action:

```
@log_contents = File.read('log/production.log') # Or another log file
```

And display it in the view:

```
<pre><%= @log_contents %></pre>
```

But beware; those logfiles tend to grow pretty large, so you might want to load and show just the last X lines.

Comment: It is terrify decision - to show ur log-flle in my mind.  There are more much clean methods for that tasks.

Comment: Well, write a better answer if you have one, but don't blame me if the author wants something that you think is *not done*.

Comment: Because u just try to ans the question, but there is more important question - what is "did he need exactly that?" - show production.log for Checking some data - is NOT rails-way, i ans him at the comments, and wait for him reaction.

Comment: In my mind - check application work with something like `tail -f log/production.log` - bad way, if i offend u - execuse me, just im adept of ror.